# How to convert a list of strings to list of dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I have a string with format:

```
["('colA':'datA1', 'colB':'datB1', 'colC':'datC1')",
 "('colA':'datA2', 'colB':'datB2', 'colC':'datC2')",
 ..........
 "('colA':'datAn', 'colB':'datBn', 'colC':'datCn')]
```

And i need to obtain a dict:

```
[{'colA': 'datA1', 'colB': 'datB1', 'colC': 'datC1'},
 {'colA': 'datA2', 'colB': 'datB2', 'colC': 'datC2'},
 ..........
 {'colA': 'datAn', 'colB': 'datBn', 'colC': 'datCn'}]
```

If possible I need to do it with Python's own functions or at least without using loops, but I do not know if this is possible.

Comment: Where does 'jack' come from? That is not in the original data. Nor is Sape. Where do the number 4098 and 4130 come from? From calculations?

Comment: Sorry, error from the clipboard. Thanks for pointing it out. I edit

Comment: hehe if it werent for the ( and ) in the string you could run eval() on each string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @nexus66 suggested, here's a more streamlined version of [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40823270/2617068):

```
l = ["('colA':'datA1', 'colB':'datB1', 'colC':'datC1')",
 "('colA':'datA2', 'colB':'datB2', 'colC':'datC2')",
 "('colA':'datAn', 'colB':'datBn', 'colC':'datCn')"]
result = [dict(
               item.replace("'", '').split(':')
               for item in s[1:-1].split(', ')
               )
          for s in l]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Thank you for the two answers you have given me. I prefer this one for not using an additional module.

Answer (score 11):

Replace the parentheses with curly braces and use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
l = ["('colA':'datA1', 'colB':'datB1', 'colC':'datC1')",
 "('colA':'datA2', 'colB':'datB2', 'colC':'datC2')",
 "('colA':'datAn', 'colB':'datBn', 'colC':'datCn')"]
result = [ast.literal_eval('{%s}' % item[1:-1]) for item in l]
```

The result:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(result)
[{'colA': 'datA1', 'colB': 'datB1', 'colC': 'datC1'},
 {'colA': 'datA2', 'colB': 'datB2', 'colC': 'datC2'},
 {'colA': 'datAn', 'colB': 'datBn', 'colC': 'datCn'}]
```

Comment: this is the proper answer - using plain `eval` like the other suggests can be dangerous. See http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using `eval`(as it's unsafe) function and rely on proper dict structure(in *json* representation). Use the following approach with `re.sub` and `json.loads` functions:

```
import json, re

d = ["('colA':'datA1', 'colB':'datB1', 'colC':'datC1')",
 "('colA':'datA2', 'colB':'datB2', 'colC':'datC2')",
 "('colA':'datAn', 'colB':'datBn', 'colC':'datCn')"]

try:
    l = [json.loads('{' + re.sub(r'\'', '"', s).strip('()') + '}') for s in d]
    print(l)
except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as err:
    print('JSONDecodeError: ', err)
```

The output:

```
[{'colC': 'datC1', 'colA': 'datA1', 'colB': 'datB1'}, {'colC': 'datC2', 'colA': 'datA2', 'colB': 'datB2'}, {'colC': 'datCn', 'colA': 'datAn', 'colB': 'datBn'}]
```

Comment: What sort of exception is that bare `except:` supposed to catch?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, it can be *bare* in some simple cases, but now I've added specific Exception type, see my update. In more strict(real) situations, of course,  we can `raise Exception('...')`

Answer (score 1):

My solution to your question without importing any module:

```
my_input = ["('colA':'datA1', 'colB':'datB1', 'colC':'datC1')",
 "('colA':'datA2', 'colB':'datB2', 'colC':'datC2')",
 "('colA':'datAn', 'colB':'datBn', 'colC':'datCn')"]

global_list =[]
for i in my_input:
    intern_dict = {}
    for j in i.replace("(", "").replace(")", "").split(","):
        c = j.split(":")
        intern_dict["".join(c[0].replace("'", "").strip())] = "".join(c[1].replace("'","").strip())     
    global_list.append(intern_dict)

print("Type of global_list: {0}\n".format(type(global_list)))
print(global_list)
print("\nType of elements inside global_list\n")
for i in global_list:
    print("{0}\tType: {1}".format(i, type(i)))
```

Output:

```
Type of global_list: <class 'list'>

[{'colA': 'datA1', 'colC': 'datC1', 'colB': 'datB1'}, {'colA': 'datA2', 'colC': 'datC2', 'colB': 'datB2'}, {'colA': 'datAn', 'colC': 'datCn', 'colB': 'datBn'}]

Type of elements inside global_list

{'colA': 'datA1', 'colC': 'datC1', 'colB': 'datB1'} Type: <class 'dict'>
{'colA': 'datA2', 'colC': 'datC2', 'colB': 'datB2'} Type: <class 'dict'>
{'colA': 'datAn', 'colC': 'datCn', 'colB': 'datBn'} Type: <class 'dict'>
```

Comment: This algorithm has some glaring oddities, such as the unnecessary generator expression with `k for k in...`.

Comment: `''.join(k for k in iterable)` accomplishes the same result as `''.join(iterable)`.

Comment: Yes ! You're right. I edited my answer. Thanks for pointing the oddities.

Comment: The entire thing could just be `result = [dict(item.replace("'", '').split(':') for item in s[1:-1].split(', ')) for s in my_input]`.

Comment: Awesome ! You should post your solution. It's more pythonic !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129121/discussion-between-nexus66-and-tigerhawkt3).

Answer (score -3):

Use json,

```
import json

lst = "yourstringhere"

dict = json.load(lst)
```